# Find a minimal polynomial of a primitive 5-th root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{-7})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{-7})$ be the base field and $L=K(\zeta_5)$ where $\zeta_5$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity. I know that the extension $L/K$ is unramified of degree $2$.

Now I would like to find a minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$ over $K$. I know that such a minimal polynomial must divide $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = \frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$, i.e. it will split into two quadratic polynomials (which both are potential minimal polynomials of $\zeta_5$). But aside from that, I don't know how to compute the actual factors.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you know how $\Phi_5(x)$ factors over the reals? Given that the splitting field of $\Phi_5(x)$ over any field in characteristic $\neq5$ is cyclic, if it factors as two quadratics, the factorization needs to be the same.

Comment: I seem to have posted that factorization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198156/11619). I think $\Phi_5(x)$ factors into two quadratics over a field $F$ if and only if $F$ contains $\sqrt5$. Is $\sqrt5$ an element of $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Given a prime *p* not dividing *n* and a *p*-adic local field $M$ with residual field $\mathbf F_q$, with $q=p^f$, it is classically known that $M(\zeta_n)/M$ is unramified  cyclic, with Galois group generated by the Frobenius automorphism $s$ determined by $s(\zeta_n)= {\zeta_n}^q$ . In particular $[M(\zeta_n):M]=r$, the smallest integer $r\ge 1$ s.t. $q^r \equiv 1$ mod $n$. See e.g. Serre's "Local Fields", chap. IV,§4, prop. 16. Applying this theorem with your notations $K=\mathbf Q_3 (\sqrt {-7})$ and $L=K(\zeta_5)$, and accepting that $K/\mathbf Q_3$ is quadratic unramified, we find here that $\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5)/\mathbf Q_3$ and $K(\zeta_5)/K$ are unramified (cyclic) of respective degrees degree $4$ and $2$. But a fixed algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_3$ contains a *unique* unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_3$ of given degree, so that $\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5)=K(\zeta_5)$. In particular, $K$ coincides with the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5)/\mathbf Q_3$, namely $K=\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5 +{\zeta_5}^{-1})$, and the minimal polynomial of $K(\zeta_5)/K$ is $X^2 -(\zeta_5 +{\zeta_5}^{-1})X + 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\mathbb{Q}_3(\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1})$ is the unique quadratic subfield? And how did you derive the minimal polynomial in the end? I think there might be something wrong with that since it does not seem to divide $x^4+x^3+\dots+1$.

Comment: You are right, I skipped too hastily over the role of $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-7})$. Recall that your question was to find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$ over $K$. I edited my answer above. It remains only to justify why the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5)/\mathbf Q_3$ coincides with $k=\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5 +{\zeta_5}^{-1})$. This is because   $k$ is contained in $\mathbf Q_3(\zeta_5)$ and is fixed by the automorphism of order $2$ which sends $\zeta_5$ to ${\zeta_5}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+2\zeta_5+2\zeta_5^9)^2=5$$
(expand the LHS then use $\sum_{n=0}^4 \zeta_5^n=0$)

Thus the minimal polynomial is $$(x-\zeta_5)(x-\zeta_5^9)=x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2} x+1$$
Where
$$\sqrt5 = \sqrt{-7} \sqrt{-5/7}=\sqrt{-7} \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2\choose k}(-1-5/7)^k$$ $$=\sqrt{-7} \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2\choose k}(-4/7)^k 3^k \in \Bbb{Z}_3[\sqrt{-7}]$$

Note: in fact it is $x^2-\frac{1 \pm \sqrt5}{2} x+1$ and $\sqrt5= \pm \sqrt{-7} \sqrt{-5/7}$ and which pair of 5-th root of unity I chose is implied by the sign I chose

Comment: Could you please explain why exactly the last infinite sum is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_3$? I just don't see why you would write it this way.

Comment: $c_k={1/2\choose k}(-4/7)^k \in \Bbb{Z}_3$ (as ${1/2\choose k}=\lim_{m\to \infty} {(3^m-1)/2\choose k}$) so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k 3^k$ is a convergent $3$-adic series, it converges in the $|.|_3$ absolute value, it is in $\Bbb{Z}_3$